# Can I restore Windows while dual booting Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I'm wondering if I can restore Windows to factory settings while having a dual-booted Ubuntu (and preferably also removing Ubuntu in the process).

- Windows is running on a 120 GB SSD (`C:\`)
- Ubuntu is running on a 1 TB HDD (`D:\`) with 200 GB partition for Ubuntu the rest is games & stuff.

The first thing that runs when I start the computer is grub, where I get an option to load Ubuntu or Windows boot loader.

Which I think I can change to run Windows first in the BIOS?

Can I restore Windows to factory settings and also reformat `D:\` drive where Ubuntu is stored without it causing problems?

Edit: Windows 10 is my windows version. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Restoring Windows Depends on the Version. What Version of windows do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: @SharadGautam Windows 10.

Comment: " I'm wondering if I can restore Windows to factory settings while having a dual-booted Ubuntu (and preferably also removing Ubuntu in the process)." - You want to keep Ubuntu or not?

Comment: Also, resetting Windows probably automatically replaces grub.

Comment: You could also do it beforehand using the bootrec command from the Windows Installation Disc

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your Windows installation device *(DVD or USB)*, from there you can restore Windows to factory settings and format partitions.

You could also boot into Windows and then press the **Windows logo key  +L** to get to the sign-in screen, then hold the **Shift** key down while you select **Power**  > **Restart** in the lower-right corner of the screen. After your PC restarts, select **Troubleshoot** > **Reset this PC**.

If you can't get to the sign-in screen, use a recovery drive or installation media to reset your PC (*like we said before*).

More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options)